# ([firebase_storage/no-bucket] No default storage bucket could be found. Ensure you have correctly followed the Getting Started guide.)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am a 2nd year student and newbie using Flutter and Firebase.

I'm having a problem not being able to upload items to Firebase storage. As you can see, I have downloaded the full libraries and connected to Firebase, but I can't access it. Please help me fix

[Setting on firebase storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoeXK.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbOjm.jpg)

[connect with Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU6vX.png)

[Was add lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nTh8.jpg)

I want when adding items and uploading, firebase creates a new collection like in [this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvC8U.png)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: provide the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and error in text form.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.